# MemoryError using json.dumps()

Tags: python, mysql, json, sqlalchemy, out-of-memory

I would like to know which one of `json.dump()` or `json.dumps()` are the most efficient when it comes to encoding a large array to json format.

Can you please show me an example of using `json.dump()`?

Actually I am making a Python CGI that gets large amount of data from a MySQL database using the ORM SQlAlchemy, and after some user triggered processing, I store the final output in an Array that I finally convert to Json.

But when converting to JSON with :

```
 print json.dumps({'success': True, 'data': data}) #data is my array
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/script/cgi/translate_parameters.py", line 617, in     &lt;module&gt;
f.write(json.dumps(mytab,default=dthandler,indent=4))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 250, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 209, in encode
    chunks = list(chunks)
MemoryError
```

So, my guess is using `json.dump()` to convert data by chunks. Any ideas on how to do this?

Or other ideas besides using `json.dump()`?

Comment: I don't know the implementation details but `dumps` outputs to a string, which must be built up and held in memory. `dump` writes out to a file, which I assume will be streaming and not keep the result in memory.

Comment: `chunk`s are yielded by `JSON.Encoder().iterencode()` generator. See my answer.

Answer (score 10):

You can simply replace

```
f.write(json.dumps(mytab,default=dthandler,indent=4))
```

by

```
json.dump(mytab, f, default=dthandler, indent=4)
```

This should "stream" the data into the file.

Comment: This doesn't work, even assuming `mytab` in your example is a JSON-serialisable object, `json.dump()` doesn't know which object you're dumping. In addition, even trying that still produces `MemoryError` for large objects.

Comment: Right .. forgot mytab as argument. Fixed. Concerning Memory it might be worth trying other json libraries hoping for a more memory efficient implementation...

Comment: Found a workaround eventually, posting my answer `:]`

Answer (score 8):

**The `JSON` module will allocate the entire JSON string in memory before writing, which is why `MemoryError` occurs.**

To get around this problem, use [`JSON.Encoder().iterencode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.iterencode):

```py
with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
    for chunk in json.JSONEncoder().iterencode(object_to_encode):
        f.write(chunk)
```

However note that this will generally take quite a while, since it is writing in many small chunks and not everything at once.

---

*Special case:*

I had a Python object which is a list of dicts. Like such:

```py
[
    { "prop": 1, "attr": 2 },
    { "prop": 3, "attr": 4 }
    # ...
]
```

I could `JSON.dumps()` individual objects, but the dumping whole list generates a `MemoryError` To speed up writing, I opened the file and wrote the JSON delimiter manually:

```py
with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
    f.write('[')

    for obj in list_of_dicts[:-1]:
        json.dump(obj, f)
        f.write(',')

    json.dump(list_of_dicts[-1], f)
    f.write(']')
```

You can probably get away with something like that if you know your JSON object structure beforehand. For a general use, just use `JSON.Encoder().iterencode()`.

Comment: That is just what `json.dump` does: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.10/Lib/json/__init__.py#l183

Comment: Yes, but iterencode() is too slow if you try large objects - It is best to divide chunks down to where your memory can handle, then pass it all to encode() at once.

Comment: @XavierHo Thank you so so much - a hidden gem!