# Is there a way other than using json.dumps when writing out very large JSON dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have the following block in my code:

```
import codecs
import json
outs = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)
tree = generate_json_tree(...)
outs.write(json.dumps(tree,encoding='utf-8'))
```

The function `generate_json_tree` generates a JSON tree which is then dumped into `stdout`.

When `tree` is very large, I get an out of memory crash when invoking `json.dumps`. Assuming that I can't get a 'bigger boat' to run this (i.e. a machine with more RAM etc), is there any way to output large dicts to `stdout`? More efficient alternatives to `json.dumps` perhaps?

Comment: Could you please supply a partial dump of `tree`? The structure of it might change the answer.

Comment: Why do you want to dump something big enough to cause a out of memory crash to stdout? Surely it would be too big to read.

Comment: @sweeneyrod: generally speaking a program doesn't know where stdout is redirected to. It might be a file, or `grep`, or `less`. That is to say size of output is the user's problem and they get what they ask for ;-)

Comment: @sweeneyrod the out-of-memory error is due to the huge size of the JSON string. If the structure fits in memory, then it should be reasonably possible to print it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Json dump() Vs Json dumps()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239613/json-dump-vs-json-dumps)