# MemoryError with json.dumps() in AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, json, dictionary, aws-lambda, out-of-memory

I would like to dump a dict object in an AWS Lambda function [Python], with already the maximum allocated memory.

```
json_dump = json.dumps(my_dict, ensure_ascii=False)
json_encoded = json_dump.encode('utf-8')
```

With huge dictionaries, I get the following error:

```
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps\n    **kw).encode(obj)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 202, in encode
return ''.join(chunks) 
MemoryError
```

I need to store the dumped object in variable and not direct to a file because I need to encode it as a string.

Any ideas or different solutions?

Comment: Its already posted in Stack overflow ref this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239613/memoryerror-using-json-dumps